# How to analyze code files (Java, PHP, Python) for malicious code?

Tags: windows, machine-learning, malware-analysis

How can we analyze files like .jar or .php or .py files for malicious code?

I need to automate the analysis process using machine learning. What should be the features in these cases?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Uploading to VirusTotal would be the most viable method, but you could theoretically detect the file type and do behavioural and etc analysis automatically.

Comment: @SirMuffington Thanks. Behavioural analysis of what? Java Virtual Machine or what?

Comment: So, code files? Python, PHP, Java? How to detect that there isn't malicious code? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+analyze+py+files+for+malicious+code and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173059/what-are-easy-checks-to-identify-malware-in-python-code

Comment: Once you craft the better-worded question, you can search for this on your own. I provided links above.

Comment: @SamuelSmith of the executed code. This question is still salvagable, just needs a bit of editing.